# Auto close window using swift language osx

Tags: macos, swift

I know this might be a very silly question but I'm a newbie for the Swift Programming Language.

I am building a sample mac application handles the user authentication. My question is how to close the window automatically using the swift.

I have tried

```
var window = NSWindow()
window.close()
```

but gives the error related to thread and opens the debugger

Please help

Comment: Use a transient popover. Of course there are plenty other ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Swift, `self.view.window?.close()` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

How do you mean "autoclose?, i.e. when it becomes visible, it closed? Have a look at ""NSWindowController:windowWillLoad:"

i.e.:

```
import Cocoa

class window: NSWindowController {
  override func windowWillLoad()
  {
    self.callFunctionToUnloadWindow();
  }
}
```

That is called immediately before the window loads.

Other than that, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That would probably not make much sense to close a window as soon as it appears. The OP wants to enter a password. He likely did not think over the use case as entering a pw means: enter/ok which will call `performClose"

Comment: @Adrian Nope.. What I wanted to ask is after my authentication the application which I have opened should be closed automatically.. like NSWindow().close().. Also I am writing entire under the ViewController but not in NSWindowController

Comment: On that note, what I'd do is use a timer on a background thread (timers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html).. There's loads of nice GCD friendly timers on  GitHub... When there's been any activity, i.e. keystrokes, or mouseDowns, the reset the timer.. If none, then let it tick away and when it hits x seconds/minutes, fire "[window orderOut:nil];"